# Simplifying the Big-O Complexity of this Exponential Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, combinatorics, exponential, binomial-coefficients

I have a counting algorithm for which I am trying to get a general big-o description.  It is horribly nested and horribly exponential.  Here it is:

```
 1. For each T_i in T
 2. For k = 1 to max_k
 3. For each of 2^k*(n choose k) items
 4. For each t in T_i
 5. check if the item is in t...etc.
```

Here is a line-by-line idea of each running time

1. This is a simple partitioning and I'm going to just give it a constant c1.
2. max_k is a small number, always less than n, perhaps around 4 or 5.  I will use k below.
3. This loop always runs 2^k*(n choose k) times
4. By considering line 1 constant, we can generalize this line and know it will never fire more than 2^n times in total in worst case, but generally will run a fraction of 2^n times, so we will call this one (2^n)/c2
5. This is the simple if-statement operation inside all these loops, so c3.

Multiplying all these together gives:

```
c1 * k * 2^k * (n choose k) * (2^n)/c2 * c3
```

Since I want a big-O representation, ignoring constants gives:

```
k * 2^k * (n choose k) * (2^n)
```

It is known that (n choose k) is bounded above by (n * e / k)^k, so:

```
O(k * 2^k * (n * e / k)^k * (2^n))
```

My question is, what can I ignore here...  2^n is certainly the dominating term since n is always larger than k, and typically much more so.  Can this be simplified to O(2^n)?  Or O(2^terrible)?  Or should I leave in the 2^k, as in O(2^k * 2^n)?  (or leave all the terms in?)

My understanding is that if k or max_k can compete or surpass n, then they are vital.  But since they are always dominated, can they be discarded like lower order terms of polynomial running times?  I suppose all the exponential running time mess is confusing me.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My understanding is that if k or max_k can compete or surpass n, then
>   they are vital

True, but the other way around isn't - meaning - it cannot be ignored when it comes to big O notation, even if it does not compete with n. **It can be ignored only if max_k is bounded with a constant** (there is a constant `c` such that `k <= c`). For example - `O(n * logk)` algorithms, are not `O(n)`, since the k factor is not bounded and thus there exists a `k` such that `nlogk > c*n` for every constant `c`.

Since the expression you got is a product, all you can ignore are constants, which in your case - is only `e` getting you `O(k*2^k * (n/k)^k * 2^n)`.

If `k` is *bounded*, then you can remove it from the expression as well in big O notation, and you will get `O(n^k* 2^n)`. Note that even in this case, although `n^k << 2^n`, it still cannot be ignored, because for every constant c there exists some `n` such that `c*2^n < n^k *2^n`, so the algorithm is not a `O(2^n)` one.

Smaller factors can be ignored when it comes to addition. If `k < n` then `O(n + k) = O(n)`, because there is a constants `c,N` such that for all `n > N`: `c*n < n + k`, but this is of course not true when dealing with product.

Comment: If it is true that n is always greater than k, is that sufficient for bounding k and thus removing it?  I think that's what you are saying but I want to be sure.  Your n*lg(k) example is quite clear -- thank you for that.

Comment: @Chucktown: `If it is true that n is always greater than k, is that sufficient for bounding k and thus removing it?` No. When we say `k is bounded` we mean there is a *CONSTANT* `c` such that `k < c`. I'll edit to clarify it.

Comment: @amit: Excellent -- thank you for clarifying.  So, since I am the inventor of this algorithm, if I state that k can never be greater than, say, 20, then I now have my c, thus bounding k by a constant rather than n, thus yielding my simpler-to-type run time.  Would you agree with this?

Comment: @Chucktown: Yes. If you know that `k` is guaranteed to be smaller then 20 (or any other constant), then you get: `k*2^k * (n/k)^k * 2^n <= 20 * 2^20 * (n/20)^20 * 2^n` which is in `O(n^20 * 2^n)`. Note that the only `k` which is not ignored is in the exponent - since it influences `(n/k)^k`.

Comment: @amit: Your answers are awesome.  Thanks for your contribution here, and based on your reputation score, a bazillion other places too.